# undefined method `pagy' for #<UsersController:0x000000000267a0>

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6.1

i used gem pagy but i found error NoMethodError in UsersController#index .

```
def index
    @q = User.ransack(params[:q])
    #@users = @q.result(distinct: true)
    @pagy, @users = pagy(@q.result(distinct: true))
    authorize @users
end
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have added `include Pagy::Backend` in `users_controller.rb` or `application_controller.rb`

Comment: ok, i will checking that place.